# Why when I compile I get username and password are not accepted?

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

Here is the code that I want to compile

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
def send_mail(email, password, text):
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com:465")
        server.login(email, password)
        server.sendmail(email, email, text)
        text = msg.as_string() 
        server.quit()
        
f = open("c1.png")
send_mail("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxxxxx",f)
```

and the output

[image: the error]

Here is what I tried so far:

- allowed less secure apps
- waited for 1 hour after allowing

Comment: Did you close multi-factor authentication

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using gmail through python without smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623017/using-gmail-through-python-without-smtp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to generate a password from [apps password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) and use that code instead of the users actual password.

> An App Password is a 16-digit passcode that gives an app or device restricted access to your Google Account without having to divulge your personal password and complete access to your Google Account.

more info on [Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

This is normally due to the user having 2fa enabled.

- [How I send emails with Python. In 2.2 minutes flat!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72pvM3whUms)
- [How I fixed fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Another option would be to use xoauth2.

- [2023: How I access GMail SMTP without enabling 2fa. (Python oauth2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1U3pwIBAIM)

Comment: I tried it there were no compile errors which is a good indicator but I cant see my mail why?

Comment: Just to clarify. the following codes have errors so use the same procedure as @DalmTo said but use the code from "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-attachment-gmail-account-using-python/"