# Using gmail through python without smtp

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, google-oauth

As of may 30th, smtp is no longer accepted.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&ref_topic=7188673

What is the new way to make a simple python emailer rather than a full application with the "login with google" option?

Not sure why I was asked for the code and error, given that I already diagnosed the issue and was asking for alternative methods.
Here it is.  Its a handy emailer that texts me to workout when I work at home.

```
import time
import smtplib
import random
gmail_user = 'usernameImNotSharing@gmail.com'
gmail_password = 'TheCorrectPassword'

sent_from = gmail_user
to = ['myphonenumber@vtext.com']
exercises = ['push ups', 'jumps in place', '20lb curls', 'tricep extensions', 'quarter mile runs']
levels = [1, 2, 3]
level1 = ['10', '15', '16', '20', '1']
level2 = ['15', '30', '30', '40', '2']
level3 = ['20', '50', '48', '70', '4']
while True:
    if int(time.strftime('%H')) > 9:
        if int(time.strftime('%H')) < 23:
            abc = random.uniform(0, 1)
            picker = random.randint(0, 4)
            if abc < 0.3:
                level = level1
            if 0.3 < abc and abc < 0.8:
                level = level2
            if abc > 0.8:
                level = level3
            exersize = exercises[picker]
            amount = level[picker]
            try:
                subject = f'Test'
                body = f'Do {amount} {exersize}'
                server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
                server.ehlo()
                server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
                server.sendmail(sent_from, to, body)
                server.close()
                print('Email sent!')
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)
            time.sleep(random.randint(1500, 4800))
    time.sleep(100)
```

error:

> (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials jj1-20020a170903048100b00163247b64bfsm7655137plb.115 - gsmtp')

Solved below: SMTP is still accepted for app passwords.
App passwords creation steps can be found here, but you must enable 2 factor auth first, before app passwords can be created.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833
https://myaccount.google.com/security

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  I would like to see how you are trying to do this currently.  Also please include any error messages

Comment: @DaImTo done althought I dont feel anything important was added. The error points u to the doc I linked originally.  I believe a lower answer about app passwords may be suffiecient, but appears that app passwords may not be possible unless you enable 2fa

Comment: Including your code in your question is a good practice.   It allows me to copy your code and show you exactly how to fix it using the apps password.   Apps password works fine with 2fa i have it enabled on my account and i have been testing with it all day.  No problems.

Comment: that may be true, but I think i need to make a new dedicated email account as Id rather not have 2fa on this and slow down logins elsewhere

Comment: Security does slow things down.  TBH never use your standard account for authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction after May 30 2022, sending the users actual password is no longer accepted by googles smtp server

You should configuring an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en#:%7E:text=An%20App%20Password%20is%20a,2%2DStep%20Verification%20turned%20on.) this works.  Then replace the password in your code with this new apps password.

> An App Password is a 16-digit passcode that gives a less secure app or device permission to access your Google Account. App Passwords can only be used with accounts that have 2-Step Verification turned on.

```
gmail_user = 'usernameImNotSharing@gmail.com'
gmail_password = 'AppsPassword'
```

This is normally due to the user having 2fa enabled.

- [How I send emails with Python. In 2.2 minutes flat!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72pvM3whUms)
- [How I fixed fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Another option would be to use [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol).

- [2023: How I access GMail SMTP without enabling 2fa. (Python oauth2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1U3pwIBAIM)

Comment: Noting in the main post, this only works if you have an app password.  And app passwords can only be created AFTER you enable 2 FACTOR AUTHENTICATION

Comment: its at the top of the page I linked on how to create one.

Answer (score -1):

```
import smtplib

host = "server.smtp.com"
server = smtplib.SMTP(host)
FROM = "testpython@test.com"
TO = "bla@test.com"
MSG = "Subject: Test email python\n\nBody of your message!"
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MSG)

server.quit()
print ("Email Send")
```

Comment: I can make this from my mac, but in my oldish debian this error remains. I wonder if this is related to openssl or some other cryptography in debian?