# SMTP authentication issue with Python - Error 535: Username and Password not accepted

Tags: python, authentication, error-handling, smtp, gmail

**I'm encountering an issue while running a Python script (test_smtp.py) that involves SMTP authentication with Gmail. The specific error message I'm getting is:**

```
Error: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w14-20020adfee4e000000b0033609750752sm6314914wro.8 - gsmtp')
```

*Here's the content of the test_smtp.py script:*

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from configparser import ConfigParser

def send_test_email():
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")

    sender_email = config.get("Email", "sender_email")
    receiver_email = config.get("Email", "receiver_email")
    password = config.get("Email", "password")

    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "Test Email"
    message["From"] = sender_email
    message["To"] = receiver_email

    text = "Just a test email."
    part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
    message.attach(part1)

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as server:
            server.login(sender_email, password)
            server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
        print("Email sent successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending email: ", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_test_email()
```

*I have verified that the .ini file (config.ini) is correct. The relevant code for reading the configuration is as follows :*

```ini
[Email]
sender_email = favmusic31@gmail.com
receiver_email = acccountff@gmail.com
password = passwword :(
```

The script (test_smtp.py) is expected to send a test email using the provided Gmail account credentials.

Comment: i get the same error. i believe that you have to sign in to the email provider and authenticate in some way. It will be useful to see an answer. . .

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/67360013/1841839

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why when I compile I get username and password are not accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360013/why-when-i-compile-i-get-username-and-password-are-not-accepted)